# worpress query very slow how to improve?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a wordpress website with a db of 1.7gb the wp postmeta its more the 2.5mln records, it is very slow and with query monitor i found there is several queries very slow for example this take 9 sec to get results. I am a dummy in database optimization and i don't know from where to start :-(

```
SELECT wwp_posts.ID
FROM wwp_posts
LEFT JOIN wwp_term_relationships
ON (wwp_posts.ID = wwp_term_relationships.object_id)
WHERE 1=1
AND wwp_posts.ID NOT IN (371814,371800,371866,371965,371908,371964,371924)
AND ( wwp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (37,40,50,51,53,55,59,62,16242,20324,34472,39743,42702,49211)
AND wwp_posts.ID NOT IN (
SELECT object_id
FROM wwp_term_relationships
WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (45,63,12061,12062,12063,12064,12065,12066,12067,12068,12069,25954,35506,47353,47836,48179,49211) ) )
AND ((wwp_posts.post_type = 'post'
AND (wwp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
OR wwp_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled'
OR wwp_posts.post_status = 'private')))
GROUP BY wwp_posts.ID
ORDER BY wwp_posts.post_date DESC
LIMIT 0, 6
```